# Smarter way to update td content in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm currently running an html and jQuery code that works but looks very ugly for me. I would really appreciate suggestion to do this more smarter.

**Goal:** update cells of a php generated table using an input field. Each cells contains a basic value which should be multiplied by the input.

Currently, I read the value of the input, take the basic value of each cell from an hidden input and rewrite the whole html of each cell ( hidden input + updated data).

Html code:

```
<table id='tbl'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Quantity:
                <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="1_1" type="hidden" value="11"><span>11</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="1_2" type="hidden" value="12"><span>12</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="2_1" type="hidden" value="21">21
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="2_2" type="hidden" value="22">22
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="3_1" type="hidden" value="31">31
           </td>
            <td>
                <input name="2_2" type="hidden" value="32">32
           </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script:

```
$('#quantity').keyup(function () {
    var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if (quantity == "" || isNaN(quantity))
        quantity = 1;
    $('#tbl tbody tr td').map(function () {
        var $row = $(this);
        var $refvalue = $row.find(':input[type=hidden]').val();
        var $refname = $row.find(':input[type=hidden]').attr('name');
        $row.html('<input name="' + $refname + '" type="hidden" value="' + $refvalue + '">' + $refvalue * quantity);
    });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5KKrD/

Is there a better way to do ? I'm able to change both table, js and so on.

Regards

Comment: why do you use `':input[type=hidden]'` instead of just `'input[type=hidden]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my approach - use `data` attribute (instead of a hidden input) to pass the multiplier, e.g.:

```
<td class="cell" data-value="11">11</td>
```

with this - you can grab the value very easily using jquery, e.g.:

```
$('.cell').data('value')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5KKrD/3/)

Comment: Hi, you pointed it. It's excatly the kind of idea I was looking for. Changes are made and it'works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @JBD glad to be of help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have refined your code a bit,its working smoothly

**JS CODE:**

```
$('#quantity').keyup(function () {
if ($(this).val()) {
    var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
    if (quantity == "" || isNaN(quantity)) quantity = 1;
    $('#tbl tbody tr td input').each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        var mulVal = row.val() * quantity;
        $(this).attr('value', mulVal);
        $(this).parent().find('span').text(mulVal);
        //var $refvalue  = $row.find(':input[type=hidden]').val();
        //var $refname = $row.find(':input[type=hidden]').attr( 'name' );
        //$row.html( '<input name="'+ $refname +'" type="hidden" value="'+ $refvalue + '">' + $refvalue * quantity );

    });
}
});
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<table id='tbl'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Quantity:
            <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1">
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="1_1" type="hidden" value="11" /><span>11</span>

        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="1_2" type="hidden" value="12" /><span>12</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="2_1" type="hidden" value="21" /><span>21</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="2_2" type="hidden" value="22" /><span>22</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="3_1" type="hidden" value="31" /><span>31</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="2_2" type="hidden" value="32" /><span>32</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5KKrD/5/)**

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit over-kill for your needs, but this is what backbone.js aims to do - remove data from the HTML DOM and instead treats it Models and Views.

http://backbonejs.org/#examples

Apart from that, what's wrong with your current approach  - what specifically do you want to improve?

Answer (score 0):

The code cleaned up a bit:

```
$('#quantity').keyup(function() {
    var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val());
    quantity = ( quantity == ""  || isNaN( quantity ) ? 1 : quantity;

    $('#tbl tbody tr td').map(function() {
        var $hiddenElement = $(this).find(input[type='hidden']);
        $(this).html( '<input name="'+ $(hiddenElement).attr('name') +'" type="hidden" value="'+ $(hiddenElement).val() + '">' +   (parseFloat($(hiddenElement).val()) * quantity) );
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think yours is just fine, the only thing I would personally do to improve it is place html in a var and use it as a template to keep syntax cleaner, I would replace this

```
  $row.html( '<input name="'+ $refname +'" type="hidden" value="'+ $refvalue + '">' + $refvalue * quantity );
```

with this

```
var template ='<input name="{name}" type="hidden" value="{refvalue}">{res}</a>';
```

then

```
$row.html(template.replace('{name}', $refname) ); // and so on
```